# Updating a 3-level nested value in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

From [MongoDb's official documentation about updating] (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/#Updating-The%24positionaloperator), I read:

> The following operation queries the bios collection for the first document where the _id field equals 6 and the awards array contains a subdocument element with the by field equal to ACM. If found, the update() method updates the by field in the first matching subdocument:

```
db.bios.update(
   { _id: 6, 'awards.by': 'ACM'  } ,
   { $set: { 'awards.$.by': 'Association for Computing Machinery' } }
)
```

What if I need another nesting level here? That is, what if rather than having:

`{ _id: 6, awards: [ { by: 'ACM', prize: 1000}, { by: 'ACS', prize: 2000} ] }`

I had something like

`{ _id: 6, companies: [ { name: 'yyy', awards: [ { by: 'ACM', prize: 1000}, { by: 'ACS', prize: 2000 } ] } ] }`

And I wanted to update the one where id is 6, companies.name is 'yyy', and companies.$.awards.$.by is 'ACM'? Is this even possible in MongoDB?

Merc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you can do it using `$[]` operator:

```
db.coll.update({}, {$set: {"a.$[i].b.$[j].c": 5}},  {arrayFilters: [{"i.id": 1},{"j.c":1]});

Input: {a: [{id:1, b: [{c: 0},{c:1}]]} 
Output: {a: [{id:1, b: {[c:0},{c:5}]]}
```

You will specify all needed filters inside `arrayFilters`.

Comment: I marked this as the accepted answer. However, LUCKILY I have since switched back to MySql. Every time I feel a bit meh because of difficult queries etc., I think about my time with Mongo, and no matter how big the problem I am having is, it looks like ponies and rainbows compared to MongoDb. Seriously.

Comment: SQL "as a language" has been around for ~50 years. Mongo's syntax it's still in his early stages of development compared to SQL. 

But i feel you all the time when it comes to difficult queries or when it comes to some update addons as setOnInsert operator (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#definition) or other many things that i was used to successfully fulfill in minutes using SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid to say that YOU can NOT do it.

There is even open JIRA ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831.

You have to change the schema design until mongoDB team come up with the solution.

Comment: Jesus. Change the design of this basically means redesigning everything. The inability to update a nested field is a limitation that makes MongoDB as useful as any other relational DB. I am speechless!

Comment: (I think the first link you provided was broken)